# Closing a popup window after performing print

Tags: javascript, oracle-adf

I have a requirement tp popup a window display a pdf page, perform silent print and close the same.

```
        String s =
        "var win = window.open('PrintPopUp.jsf','_blank',\"height=300,width=200,scrollbars=no," +
        "status=no, resizable=no, screenx=0, screeny=0\");" +
"win.onclick= function(){  win.close();}"
```

I used the above code to get the popup , on click of print I write this code to my page and the following to call a servlet to generate the pdf;

```
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest)context.getExternalContext().getRequest();
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse)context.getExternalContext().getResponse();
    RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/hisprintservlet");
```

My question is this, I have been able to bring up the window, perform silent print but no matter what I do the popup wont close.

I am using IE 11 and the project uses ADF 12c.

Please help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for this..  i added an iframe to my popup window. In the body tag I added the followingg code to close ..

```
function test(win){if(win==null){alert('null');} else {setTimeout(function(win){this.close();},3000);}}
```

This works well in IE11

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the docs on Popups [here](http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/adf/TROAF/tagdoc/af_popup.html).

function showPopup(event) 
  {
    event.cancel();
    var source = event.getSource();
    var popupid="popup";
    var popup = AdfPage.PAGE.findComponentByAbsoluteId(popupId);

```
if (!popup.isPopupVisible())
{   
  var hints = {};
  hints[AdfRichPopup.HINT_LAUNCH_ID] = source.getClientId();
  hints[AdfRichPopup.HINT_ALIGN_ID] = source.getClientId(); 
  hints[AdfRichPopup.HINT_ALIGN] = AdfRichPopup.ALIGN_AFTER_START;

  popup.show(hints);
}
```

}

function hidePopup(event) 
  {
    event.cancel();
    var source = event.getSource();
    var popupId = source.getProperty("popupId");
    var isCanceled = source.getProperty("isCanceled");

```
var popup = AdfPage.PAGE.findComponentByAbsoluteId(popupId);

if (popup.isPopupVisible())
{                 
  if (isCanceled)
    popup.cancel();
  else
    popup.hide();
}
```

}

...
...

 
    Hello World!

...
...